# seeking information about driver for hp laptop.

Tags: 13.10

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 in my hp laptop.
Do i need to install drivers for my sound, Graphics, WiFi, Bluetooth etc.
or the Ubuntu have it pre-installed in it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! To answer your question we need to know your hardware info. Please open a terminal in your computer by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+t` then type `lspci` and press `Enter`. Now copy whatever appears there and paste in your description above. To paste it in the description press the `edit` button found above your question's tag(s) and paste the output(of `lspci`) there.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has preinstalled most of the drivers for the basic function.

If you are having problems:

Install soundcard drivers by:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` alsa-base alsa-base-udeb alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsa-utils-udeb alsamixergui
```

Install Wifi drivers and needed packages by :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree wicd wicd-gtk wicd-daemon wicd-cli wicd-curses
```

Install bluetooth drivers and packages by:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 python-gobject python-dbus
```

Install graphic brivers by:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```